# Change of Maven project

Tags: java, maven, tomcat7

I have a project in Maven and the problem is that I cannot change the name of the whole project. There is pom.properties file:

```
#Generated by Maven Integration for Eclipse
#Thu Dec 19 14:38:08 CET 2013
version=1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT
groupId=org.springframework.samples
m2e.projectName=project-name
m2e.projectLocation=D\:\\Project-name
artifactId=Project-name
```

and I want to change the field projectName but I cannot :/ Anyone can tell me how to change the name of the project ?

Comment: In Eclipse there is a possibility to change the name project but now I damaged project.. ://

Comment: Where do you want to change the name? Can you please show your pom.xml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to make a modification to the project pom.xml file.

Comment: In pom file I do not have a name of project..I mean I have but after changing the project in Eclipse is still as previous one.

Answer (score 0):

You can always create a new project from scratch with the new name, recreate the folder/package structure, and copy the file contents of the old project into it. This works best if the project isn't too large.

Comment: The problem is that the project is quite big :/

Answer (score 0):

If you have your project setup correctly, you only check-in your Maven pom file. You don't check-in IDE files (Eclipse, IntelliJ, etc.). In this case, the Maven names are the authoritative version. You can rename them in Maven, and if Eclipse keeps the old name, it should not be an issue.

Remember, that in Maven you have two concepts for *name*. There is `artifactId` which is the output name and is used for dependency resolution. There there is `name`, which is a human-readable name.

Just change your pom file:

```
<artifactId>project-name</artifactId>
<name>Friendly Project Name</name>
```